# Access to Context API from outside of the component being tested

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using Jest and React-testing-library to test a React component. I've rendered a component with a Context API Provider so the component has access to the Context. Unfortunately, I don't know how could I access it from outside the rendered component. In this case there is an `isUserLogged` property in the Context depending on which the component changes. But I don't know how could I change the value of this property. How could I approach this case? If mocking of the Context API required how could I do it?

In the attached code I try to access a Context using a useContext hook. The error says I can't use hooks outside of React components. And, obviously, I'm trying to access the Context outside the Context Provider so it wouldn't work anyway.

```
import { Provider, Context } from '../../context';

test('Star is not clickable for a non-registered user', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Provider><Star /></Provider>);
  const isUserLogged = useContext(Context).isUserLogged; // Error.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to render your `Provider` passing a `value` prop. That's how you would do it in your app.

```
const isUserLogged = true
render(<Provider value={{ isUserLogged }}><Star /></Provider>)
```

Comment: It could be different things. There could be another provider somewhere overwriting your value. Or maybe the context you are importing in your test is different from the one you're using in your component

Comment: One more question, Gpx. If I have two tests in one test file, the second test fails notwithstanding the true value of isUserLogged. When I comment out test number 1 everything works again. What's wrong here?

Comment: Oh, I've figured it out. Cleanup function from react-testing-library should be run afterEach test to unmount and clean up DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I access to context in order to initialise state to be ready for a function being tested:

```
let authContext

const TestWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  authContext = useContext(AuthContext)

  return children
}

const renderer = renderHook(() => useAuth(), {
  wrapper: ({ children }) => (
    <AuthProvider>
      <TestWrapper>{children}</TestWrapper>
    </AuthProvider>
  ),
})

act(() => {
  authContext.setUser(user)
})

// hook that uses the same context now have 'user' initialised
```